# How do I move Vue data to external file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, external

I'm trying to keep my Vue compontent more easy to read, and there is a massive block of data (myDataStructure) which I'd like to move to an external file:

```
 data() {
            return {
                myDataStructure: {..................}
            }
 }
```

so that I have

```
myDataStructure: variableName
```

I know I can make a global variable, but that seems messy. What is the best practice to do this? I'd prefer not to get this data from an Ajax call. I'd like Vue to compile it so that it loads together with the component.

Comment: Abstract out bits which are not relevant for the parent component/app into components which do a specific thing, then your data object will be smaller. Also having it organised, it can become pretty big without any readability issues, messy arises when you define everything on the first level.

Comment: Thank you. This was necessary to have on this level. The file was just getting annoying to work with, given the amount of scrolling I had to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use es module imports for this like this:

data-structure.js

```
export default {
  someData: false,
  otherData: [],
  moreData: ''
};
```

my-component.vue

```
import dataStructure from './data-structure.js'

export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data() {
    return dataStructure;
  }
};
```